# MVC DAL & BLL Concept

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I am used to Classic Asp, where I never used DAL/BLL concept, and now I am learning MVC and trying to stay away from BAD habits (Such as writing SQL queries within ASP page itself). I read about Data Access Layer and Business Logic Layer....they make sense, but i am trying to figure out how to put them into my current application.

Its a Shopping Cart Application.

Currently I am NOT using EF or SQL to Entities, plain old ADO.NET, where my Functions return DataTable.

Let me give you an example.

```
1 - I need to Return Products From SQL Table 
2 - My Products Model Class will hold the SQL Table output 
3 - and then I will show the output to View
```

Query involved to Bring Products

```
Select *  From Products Where title = 'Bluh'
```

ProductsModelView.vb

```
Class ProductsModelView

 Public title as string
 Public sku as string
 ....etc
End Class
```

Now my View will simply Render the Result (of List(ProductsModelView))

Now my question is...how should I structure above steps into DAL & BAL layers.

Comment: You really should take the time to learn Entity Framework and LINQ as well as MVC. It's not that hard to understand once you take the plunge and, if you program professionally with Microsoft tools, it will help keep your skill set up to date.

Comment: right....but we are using stored procedures at this time.

Comment: Entity Framework 4 and 5 work with stored procs as well as tables. EF5 with Code First works very well with an existing layer of stored procs.

Comment: One thing i dislike about EF is... If i have a database with hundreds of tables and most of the tables dont have proper relationships then how would i handle it. I like writing my raw queries without creating any table entities.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

A basic way to start is to create 3 projects:

- A DAL project
- A BLL project
- A UI project (your MVC app)

In your DAL project you should create a `repository`-class. What this class does is execute a query on the database and transform the DataTable into your model.

Your BLL project should have a `service`-class. This class has a reference to the DAL and calls the method to obtain the list of objects you need (DAL handles DB-code). In this class you can apply logic. 
NOTE: At the moment you don't seem to have any real logic in your app. That's OK, your service can just return the list from the DAL immediately. It will provide you with a place where you can add logic safely later, without affecting the data access code.

In the UI, your controller will call the service and pass the result to the view, which is then in charge of rendering the result.

This is a basic starting point. You could go further with this and completely make it loosely coupled. At the moment you still have a hard dependency from UI => BLL => DAL.

I recently wrote an article on how you can make sure you don't create hard dependencies:
http://www.kenneth-truyers.net/2013/05/12/the-n-layer-myth-and-basic-dependency-injection/

Comment: This is a good enough answer but I often see people implement a DAL and BLL just for the sake of it.  If your logic is very little and you are doing MOSTLY data access with a bit of logic, just stick with a DAL and eliminate the BLL.  I argue that the complexity of another project, layer, etc is not worth the trade off.  I always start with a DAL and then build from there if necessary.  It's always easier to add things than it is to take away.

Comment: i agree with PETE....my DAL is doing all the processing...and I find it very confusing why even bother with the BLL layer? my DAL will return the data and will populate the correct set of class(s)...do i need BLL?

Comment: It depends a bit on the app you're building of course. From my experience, once you have even a moderately complex app, a BLL layer is valuable. If the app is that small, even though the BLL has a little overhead, it won't be prohibitive (since it's that small).

Comment: The BLL layer is valuable even if you aren't doing anything complex, because it provides a Seam. When/If you eventually DO need to do more logic, you don't have to refactor the entire app to make a change. Not to mention testing, etc etc. Depending on how you build your DAL, it might not be easy to sub it out for unit/integration tests.

Comment: So if i return my data from my dal and just use my bll to return same data to my client app... Is it considered normal?  For example Dal.getProducts returns the data and then bal.getproducts simple does "return dal.getProducts"?

Comment: Well, in a real-world scenario, it will hardly ever be this simple. This will only be the case if you just list the entire DB-table without applying any rules. You need to make sure that if you have any rules, that they are applied inside your BLL. If there are no rules, then yes, it's that simple. If there are business rules and you still see this, than you have got to check where that logic is applied and move it to the BLL.